# Are there any issues with hosting your DNS records in cPanel?

Tags: dns, cpanel

I have been thinking about moving my domain over to my website hosting provider to store the DNS records inside cPanel. I believe it would be nice to keep both the website and domain together using one service.

My question is, are there any downsides to storing your DNS on your cPanel. I guess my concern would be if my hosting provider went down then I could possibly end up waiting for my DNS propagate again. If my TTL was set to 24 hours I could be experiencing a rather large downtime if I was unlucky enough.

How do other people normally reduce this risk? Should I be keeping a constant low TTL on my DNS at all times? Or should my DNS be hosted separate to my website. How do other people handle DNS downtime?

I have done some research regarding the matter but I haven't seen it discussed anywhere before and would just like some insight into the matter.

Comment: i suggest to do all DNS setting on cpanel first after that make DNS changes on domain and make sure there is no fault on cpanel DNS, after that you will not get any downtime.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was however referring to downtime after the migration. For example if your hosting goes down while your DNS is already setup in cPanel. What sort of effect does this have?

Comment: If your all dns settings are correct on cpanel than there will be no down time.

Comment: What happens if my hosting service goes down? I assume if the server is down then my DNS will also be down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer to my question which was provided by my hosting company.

They run the DNS on a clustering system which means that even if the server goes down, DNS should continue to function, so no DNS propagation would need to re-occur should the hosting server go down.

I assume this would be common practice among shared hosting companies. It's definitely interesting to know.